# Non-breakable inline code block in markdown document

Tags: html, css, markdown

I have words delimited by dashes inside of inline code block. And I don't want the browser to break them. I searched for the solution and found that there is a non-breaking hyphen `&#8209;`. But when I try to put it between backquotes markdown translates `&` into `&amp;` and the
magic doesn't work.

So, is there any simple method to make markdown's inline code block non-breakable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `&#8209;` doesn't work with the markdown editor, you could always use [**`white-space:nowrap`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

```
span { white-space:nowrap; }
```

Example usage:

```
<span>Words-with-hyphens</span>
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/sKuP2/2/)

Comment: Yes, I considered this solution. I hoped to find something without putting html stuff around at all. But seems it's impossible. Thanks, anyway. I'll accept your answer.